ECS - Mount a secret from parameter store into the container as a file
I'm trying to deploy data-prepper pipeline as a docker container on ECS (EC2). The following is what I want to replicate in ECS task definition:
version: "3.7"
services:
  data-prepper:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: data-prepper
    image: opensearchproject/data-prepper:2
    volumes:
      - ../trace_analytics_no_ssl_2x.yml:/usr/share/data-prepper/pipelines/pipelines.yaml
      - ../data-prepper-config.yaml:/usr/share/data-prepper/config/data-prepper-config.yaml
      - ../demo/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/data-prepper/root-ca.pem
    ports:
      - "21890:21890"

I stored the data-prepper-config.yaml and pipelines.yaml files as secrets in parameter store. And trying to mount these into the container as a file. Following is my task definition but when I try to create the service using the task definition, it throws the following error:
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: d9dff350-ff3e-a309-142d-9b7117d0399d, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
Afaik the above error is triggered when the app does not bootstrap correctly.
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "data-prepper",
            "image": "opensearchproject/data-prepper:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 21890,
                    "hostPort": 21890,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [
              {
                "sourceVolume": "pipelines-volume",
                "containerPath": "/usr/share/data-prepper/pipelines"
              },
              {
                "sourceVolume": "config-volume",
                "containerPath": "/usr/share/data-prepper/data-prepper-config.yaml"
              }
            ],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [
                  {
                      "name": "PREPPER-PIPELINE",
                      "valueFrom": "/ecs/data-prepper/pipelines.yaml"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "PREPPER-CONFIG",
                      "valueFrom": "/ecs/data-prepper/data-prepper-config.yaml"
                  }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/data-prepper",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "data-prepper",
    "taskRoleArn": "",
    "executionRoleArn": "",
    "networkMode": "host",
    "revision": 8,
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "pipelines-volume",
        "host": {
          "sourcePath": "<arn>:parameter/ecs/data-prepper/pipelines.yaml"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "config-volume",
        "host": {
          "sourcePath": "<arn>:parameter/ecs/data-prepper/data-prepper-config.yaml"
        }
      }
    ]
}


Where are the secrets stored, Secrets Manager or S3? Are you deploying these tasks to EC2 or Fargate? Also please update your question to clarify " it doesn't seem to be working". That isn't a valid problem statement, please describe what exactly is happening, for example are you getting an error at some point, or what?

@MarkB have edited the question to include the exact error.
Using System Manager Parameter Store to store the secrets. Also trying to deploy this task to EC2.

That error just says ECS failed to deploy after several attempts. You need to look at one of the failed tasks to see what the actual error is. Although, I'm not aware of the ability to mount Parameter Store secrets as files like you are attempting. The syntax in your volumes and secrets sections of your task definition don't look correct to me, and I can't find any documentation saying you can mount secrets this way.

Got it. Will the following solution work for my use case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416753/mount-content-from-parameter-store-into-aws-ecs-container

Yes that would certainly work.
